# Meteor manually subscribe scenario

Tags: meteor

Here is the client-side code snippet in Coffeescript -

```
Meteor.autosubscribe ->
    Meteor.subscribe "message", Session.get("message")

Template.messages.messages = (page)->
    msg = Message.find().fetch()
    showMsg = msg.slice page* PERPAGE, PERPAGE

    if msg.length and showMsg.length < PERPAGE
        Session.set "message", { created: msg[msg.length - 1].created}
    else
        return showMsg
```

The server side only publishes a small amount of records everytime.

When the client side runs out of data, it updates the selector in Session, and Meteor will rerun the template helper.

One question - Is there an elegant way to notify when no more data is returned from server-side?

I hope I can access some info in the subscribe onComplete callback, but failed:(

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_ui_listchunk

else_func Function returning HTML

Render function to be called when query is empty

Comment: wow, I haven't notice this. It's helpful, but not exactly I want.

Comment: I can put `subscribe` into `else_func`, but how can I figure out the subscription won't return any data?
And if I'm right, Meteor currently doesn't support slice/skip option under Meteor.ui.render. So the query cannot be the one exactly I want, right?

Comment: i'm a newbie, i use blade template engine. in my code i just make a "if empty template chunk like chunk else" then use meteor.ui.listChunk(People.find(), __.chunk.people, __.chunk.else), if there's nothing it uses chunk else template part.